# Disable system sounds in Unity?

Tags: unity

I've got an editor script in Unity 5 that uses the cursor position in the scene view to change objects in the scene when you press the space key. This all works perfectly, except that Unity thinks that space isn't a valid key to press, so it makes the system "boop" sound to let you know that it's invalid or that nothing happened.

So, focus is on scene view, I press space, my script triggers, and the mac system "boop" sound activates. It spams the sound if you hold it down. Is there a way to:

1. Disable the system boops in Unity

*or*

2. Add space to registered hotkeys / stop unity from triggering the system sound for a specific key

(just to be clear, the script works, I'm just wondering about disabling the sound)

Comment: Please add some code regarding this. How you are playing sound. What is your technique?

Comment: @HamzaHasan I don't really think it's relevant, just an editor script that detects a key down event in the `OnSceneGUI` function. `if (Event.current.keyCode == KeyCode.Space)` ,nothing fancier than that for key detection.